# How do I tell what resources are being devoted to hosting my web application

Tags: azure

I have a a web application that is currently hosted in Azure via publishing that application with Visual Studio. But it is unclear to me what resource(s) are devoted to hosting this web application. I am bogged down in the myriad of terms like solution, resource group, resource, etc. None of which when viewed in the portal seem to correspond to something like the amount of RAM devoted to this web application or the CPU type and speed. I am looking at hosting another web application on Azure but I would like to get a handle on this experimental one first.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the reosurce group on portal and open the Web App where the application is hosted. Then you can navigate to the AppService Plan -> Metrics to see the usage of memory and the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing. Sajeetharan's answer is great for figuring out how much CPU and memory your web app is consuming. But it sounds like you may be interested in how much CPU and memory (and other resources) are available to you.

Every Azure Web App runs in an [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans). The App Service Plan will dictate what Azure region you are physically hosted in, and the size and cost of the VM(s) that your Web App is running on.

To see what App Service Plan your Web App is running in, go to your Web App's management blade in the Azure Portal, and choose the App Service menu option. You can also click the "Scale Up" menu item, which will show you what App Service Plan you're currently on. The App Service Plan will tell you how much CPU and memory your VMs have.

Comment: Thank you.. Where do I need to go to find the costs associated with "scaling up"?